# How to disable sending data in EMUI 10.1 (Android 10) to Huawei servers?

Tags: huawei, emui

I have tablet (Huawei MediaPad M6) with EMUI 10.1 (based on Android 10).
My tablet regularly requests to the following domains:

```
pushtrs9.push.hicloud.com
grs.dbankcloud.com
grs.dbankcloud.cn
grs.dbankcloud.eu
grs.dbankcloud.asia
```

Also sometimes makes requests to the following domains:

```
query.hicloud.com
configserver.platform.hicloud.com
```

I blocked all these requests with [Blokada](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/org.blokada.alarm/) app. Also I uninstalled about 60% of all system apps via adb. This helped to get rid of some of the requests. But the above requests are still ongoing.

How to terminate all these requests? Everywhere in the license I refused to collect data and statistics. Should I uninstall more any system apps? Or disable something in the settings?